# Change layout based on field value (sitecore)

Tags: layout, sitecore, sitecore8

I have tried to use personalization to adjust the layout (personalize renderings) of a template based on the field value (ie. if "Organization" is equal to "Apple") of a piece of content, but nothing seems to work. Should I be doing this in another way?

Comment: You will need to give a bit more detailed information on what you have done  in order to give a good answer..

Comment: As @Gatogordo says, we'll need more information: How are you tracking the visitors organization? What have you tried to do to personalize, which isn't working? Are other personalizations working?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new custom rule based on Organization
2. Configure sitecore with the custom rules.If you are not sure how to configure custom rules in sitecore follow the instructions in url https://www.geekhive.com/buzz/post/2016/11/sitecore-custom-personalization-rule/
3. personalize your rendering using the above rule.

Your custom sitecore rule code should look like this

```
    public class OrganizationName<T> : WhenCondition<T> where T : RuleContext
    {
        protected override bool Execute(T ruleContext)
        {
         try
            {
              var organizationItem = Sitecore.Data.Database.GetDatabase("master").GetItem(ruleContext.NewItemId);
           var orgName = organizationItem["Organization"];
           if(orgName  == "Apple")
            {
              return true;
            }
            }
             return false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error("Unexpected error", ex);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```